# why the JSON converter doesn't use the MapPoint constructor

Tags: c#, json, uwp, json.net, esri

I created GUI  that gather geographic data form the user , the user tap on a map and place nodes where ever he likes.
I have created a class called Run_sample which holds the data that my application gathered with my GUI.
my goal was to have a load button that when the user tap it he can choose a JSON file that represents a Run_sample object and display it on the GUI map. my problem was when I tried to desterilize the Run_sample object i got - `

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unable to find a constructor to use for type Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MapPoint. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Node_list[0].starting_point.GeometryType', line 6, position 23.'`

The line of code is

```
Run_Sample loaded_sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Run_Sample>(jsonString);
```

The data structures

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
class Run_Sample
{
    public List<Node> Node_list;
    public MapPoint Global_dest = null;
    public Run_Sample(List<Node> Node_list, MapPoint Global_dest)
    {
        this.Node_list = Node_list;
        this.Global_dest = Global_dest;
    }
```

the node class

```
internal class Node
{

    public string type;
    public MapPoint starting_point = null;
    public string ID = "";
    public MapPoint Final_Dest=null;
    public List<MapPoint> check_points = new List<MapPoint>();
    public string Metadata="";
    public readonly SimpleMarkerSymbol symbol;
    public Dictionary<string, int> Lambda = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

`

Comment: Post the full error text, not just parts of the message. Your code is a bit weird too - no properties, public fields.

Comment: The error explains what's wrong anyway. The class you want to serialize *must* have either a default constructor (MapPoint doesn't have one) or one of the many constructors must .... you didn't post that part, but it says that one of the constructors must hav the `JsonConstructor` attribute. The deserializer can't guess which constructor to use, or which parameters to pass

Comment: Which JSON serializer are you using? You may be able to create a custom converter that will call [Geometry.FromJson](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/android/api-reference/html/Overload_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_Geometry_FromJson.htm).

Comment: im using the Newtonsoft.Json JSON serializer i have thought about creating a custom converter but i dont know how to do it specifically to the MapPoint object

Comment: thank you for the honest review its my first project and my first question here

Comment: I tried to test with the code you post. I created a sample class for MapPoint, Then I serialized the object and deserialized the string. Both of these two scenarios work correctly. What is the MapPoint Class? Is it a third-party library?

Comment: yes https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Geometry_MapPoint.htm

Comment: Please try to use a simple MapPoint class to test to see if the issue is related to this

Comment: @dannaor Glad to hear that!